# Detect a specific html entity character and replace it with another one

Tags: javascript, html, character, ascii, detect

Using Javascript, I want to test for the presence of a right arrow character ⇒ in a string and replace it by a down arrow character ⇓ 
Basically, do something like this:

```
if ( node.innerHTML.indexOf("⇒")!==-1 )
{
var text=node.innerHTML.replace("⇒","⇓");                         
node.innerHTML=text;
}
```

Unfortunately, the above code does not work.

The ASCII code for the above are

```
&#8658;
and
&#8659;
```

So I suppose I have to detect for the presence of a specific ASCII code in a string and then replace it with another one. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Make JSFiddle for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the replace text is not a property value of a html element or if it is that's it's ok to replace you could try:

```
node.innerHTML=node.innerHTML.replace(/⇒/ig,"⇓").replace(/\&#8658\;/ig,"&#8659;")
```